# Officially rooted HTC, denies su permission in Android Emulator app

Tags: rooting, htc, permissions

officially rooted from htcdev.com, I followed the instructions step by step and had the screen confirmation that my phone (HTC Sensation XL) is rooted.

Now when trying to gain super user access through "Android emulator", "Superuser", "Super manager" the permission is denied or the apps cannot detect if the device has been rooted.

I want to know why root access is denied after the device has been rooted successfully and how to fix this issue, am I missing extra steps or additional settings?

Comment: HTCdev has instructions for unlocking your bootloader, but I don't think it roots your phone - that is a different process. Is that what you did? How did you install Superuser?

Comment: yeah you are right "unlock bootloader" has noting to do with root. I installed Superuser from marketplace and it is all blank, it does not do anything. I am doing all these to delete some stock apps comes with the phone. My device has over 50 stock apps installed, and I believe should be the user right to permanently remove these commercial apps from the device without any hack or trick.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **"eldarerathis"** for the comment. Basically *unlock bootloader* does not mean you will have root access to your device. Even though you can install an entire new operating system still rooting your phone must be done inside the OS.

So if you trying to root your HTC device check [unrevoked.com](http://unrevoked.com). for other devices I found a reliable tutorial at http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20054428-285/how-to-root-your-android/.

please note *unlock bootloader* or *rooting* your device may void your warrantee.

Answer (score 0):

First, root your phone. If it denies root access, go to the SuperUser website and download the latest SuperUser and binary packages. After that, reboot in recovery and install the packages. Finally, boot your phone up normally and clear the data of SuperUser. Then, run SuperUser and try updating the binaries and BAAAAM works like a charm!

Comment: Makesure you unlock your boot loader first and on some devices switch to s-off